# Flask logger info

Tags: logging, flask, gunicorn

I have my Flask app running on Gunicorn and Nginx serving as the reverse proxy. I have the following logging code:

```
app.logger.error("This is an error")
app.logger.info("This is an info")
```

And I have my gunicorn executed with the following arguments

```
gunicorn --log-file /home/ubuntu/myproject/logs/gunicorn.log --log-level DEBUG --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

Now when my routine is executed I get the error message ("This is an error") on my gunicorn.log but I didn't see any ("This is an info") in the file. May I know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `--log-level=info`:

```
gunicorn --log-file /home/ubuntu/myproject/logs/gunicorn.log --log-level INFO --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. BTW in my gunicorn.log I saw something like `[2017-02-14 03:33:35 +0000] [718] [DEBUG] GET /api/logout`. Do you know what does the 718 stands for?

Comment: 718 is the process ID. It seems to be using default formatting, which is something like this: `%(asctime) [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s`